# Should I include LifecycleOwner in ViewModel?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-viewmodel

LifecycleOwner is currently needed in order for me to create an observer.

I have code which creates an Observer in the ViewModel so I attach the LifecycleOwner when retrieving the ViewModel in my Fragment.

According to Google's documentation.

Caution: A ViewModel must never reference a view, Lifecycle, or any class that may hold a reference to the activity context.

Did I break that warning and If I did, what way do you recommend me to move my creation of an observer for data return?

I only made an observer so I'm wondering if it's still valid. Since also in Google's documentation it also said.

ViewModel objects can contain LifecycleObservers, such as LiveData objects.

**MainFragment**

```
private lateinit var model: MainViewModel

/**
 * Observer for our ViewModel IpAddress LiveData value.
 * @see Observer.onChanged
 * */
private val ipObserver = Observer<String> {
    textIp.text = it
    hideProgressBar()
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
    model.attach(this)
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? =
        inflater?.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)

override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    buttonRetrieveIp.setOnClickListener {
        showProgressBar()
        model.fetchMyIp().observe(this, ipObserver) //Here we attach our ipObserver
    }
}

override fun showProgressBar() {

    textIp.visibility = View.GONE
    progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}

override fun hideProgressBar() {

    progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
    textIp.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```

**MainViewModel**

```
private var ipAddress = MutableLiveData<String>()
private lateinit var owner: LifecycleOwner

fun attach(fragment: MainFragment) {
    owner = fragment
}

/**
 * For more information regarding Fuel Request using Fuel Routing and Live Data Response.
 * @see <a href="https://github.com/kittinunf/Fuel#routing-support">Fuel Routing Support</a>
 * @see <a href="https://github.com/kittinunf/Fuel#livedata-support">Fuel LiveData Support</a>
 * */
fun fetchMyIp(): LiveData<String> {

    Fuel.request(IpAddressApi.MyIp())
            .liveDataResponse()
            .observe(owner, Observer {

                if (it?.first?.statusCode == 200) {//If you want you can add a status code checker here.

                    it.second.success {

                        ipAddress.value = Ip.toIp(String(it))?.ip
                    }
                }
            })
    return ipAddress
}
```

**Update 1: Improved ViewModel thanks to @pskink suggestion for using Transformations.**

```
private lateinit var ipAddress:LiveData<String>

/**
 * Improved ViewModel since January 23, 2018 credits to <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink">pskink</a> <a href="
 *
 * For more information regarding Fuel Request using Fuel Routing and Live Data Response.
 * @see <a href="https://github.com/kittinunf/Fuel#routing-support">Fuel Routing Support</a>
 * @see <a href="https://github.com/kittinunf/Fuel#livedata-support">Fuel LiveData Support</a>
 * */
fun fetchMyIp(): LiveData<String> {

    ipAddress = Transformations.map(Fuel.request(IpAddressApi.MyIp()).liveDataResponse(), {

        var ip:String? = ""

            it.second.success {

                ip = Ip.toIp(String(it))?.ip
            }
        ip
    })

    return ipAddress
}
```

Comment: tried `MediatorLiveData` or `Transformations#map` / `Transformations#switchMap`?

Comment: I haven't yet actually, so instead of returning a LiveData String, I'll return a MediatorLiveData and add both sources and add a single observer in my fragment right?

Comment: first try `Transformations` class - it seems that it is the easiest way - if not, when it comes to `MediatorLiveData` what you mean by "both sources"? there is one source that changes, isnt it?

Comment: My bad, I only get the source from my GET method. Hmm... I tried wrapping   the liveDataResponse() in the Transformations.map but it doesn't proceed to call my GET method. http://prntscr.com/i4bnhe I'm definitely doing something wrong here.

Comment: see [Transform LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata.html#transform_livedata)

Comment: I got it now, I was able to make it work using Transformations.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

No. If you wish to observe changes of some `LiveData` inside your `ViewModel` you can use `observeForever()` which doesn't require `LifecycleOwner`.

Remember to remove this observer on `ViewModel`'s `onCleared()` event:

```
val observer = new Observer() {
  override public void onChanged(Integer integer) {
    //Do something with "integer"
  }
}
```

...

```
liveData.observeForever(observer);
```

...

```
override fun onCleared() {
    liveData.removeObserver(observer) 
    super.onCleared()
}
```

Very good reference with examples of [observe LiveData](http://jensklin.triangulum.uberspace.de/learn-how-to-use-livedata/#Observe_changes).

Comment: This seems to be a helpful answer.  Unfortunately, the link for the observe LiveData is broken.

Answer (score 3):

**Assumptions:**

1. `Fuel` refers to your `ViewModel`
2. `Fuel.request(IpAddressApi.MyIp())` is a method in your `ViewModel`
3. `IpAddressApi.MyIp()` does not have a reference to your `LifecycleOwner`,

If all are true,then you are not violating it. So long as you are not passing a `LifecycleOwner` reference to the `ViewModel` you are safe!

**LifecycleOwner** - *relates to an Activity or Fragment as it owns the various Android Lifecycles e.g onCreate, onPause, onDestroy etc*

Comment: I've updated my question with additional information.

Fuel is my HttpClient, Fuel.request is a method in Fuel that converts a FuelRouting Interface to a request, which is where I create an observer for the return from my GET method.

Answer (score 1):

in **Kotlin** this can be something like:

```
val mObserver = Observer<List<QueueTabData>> { myString->
// do something with myString
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Should I include LifecycleOwner in ViewModel?
> Ans: **No**

The purpose of `viewmodel` is to hold UI data, so that it survives across configuration changes.
And the reason for the following

> Caution: A ViewModel must never reference a view, Lifecycle, or any class that may hold a reference to the activity context.

Is because the `viewmodel` survives configuration changes whereas `activities` don't. They are destroyed and re-created on configuration change. So, if you have any *activity context* references in viewmodel they would refer to previous activity that got destroyed.

So this leads to memory leak. And hence it is not recommended.

Furthermore,

If you have `repositories` that act as your data source we should avoid using `LiveData` for such purposes as mentioned here in the [paragraph just above the code block](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#livedata-in-architectures).
This is because `LiveData` are handled on `MainThread` that may lead to UI freeze.

We should use `kotlin flows` for such purposes.