# ViewModel manipulation in MVVM Architecture

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-room

My Problem is, that i need to preprocess data from the Room Database before showing it in my View.

**Therefore here some Context of my Application:**

Im programming a "record card" android application. Therefore i have a Room Database where all my record-cards are stored. The Information in the Entitiy is:

```
@Entitiy:
- ID
- Question
- Answer
- Topic
- Boxnumber (Box depends on how often i was right with my Answer)
```

Around the Entity i have the normal Room Setup, i found in several tutorials, with: `Dao, Database, Repository`. Furthermore i have a `ViewModel` connected to the `Repository`. And a `View` for showing the current Question connected to the `ViewModel`.

**My Idea:**

My Idea was that the `ViewModel` can hold `LiveData` of all needed Cards (with a specific Topic for example).
I need some algorithm on that data which will select me my next Card i need for the `View`. This depends on: How much cards have different boxnumbers, which cards was the last 10 Questions, etc.

**My Problem:**

In my `ViewModel` i recieve `LiveData` from the `repository`. Every Tutorial shows only displaying the Room-Database Data with an View. But i need to do some preprocessing inside the `ViewModel`. Accessing the `LiveData` with `.getValue()` is not working and only returning `null` objects. Observing the Data in the `ViewModel` is also not working, because you need an `Activity` for this.

I don't know where i should place the algorithm working with the data from the database. I don't want to put it in the `View` because i want to hold the current algorithm parameters inside the `ViewModel`.

**Some Code to understand my Program better:**

@Dao

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Karteikarte WHERE BoxnummerMixed = :Boxnummer")
LiveData<List<Karteikarte>> getKarteikartenInBoxMixed(int Boxnummer);

@Query("SELECT * FROM Karteikarte WHERE BoxnummerTopic = :Boxnummer AND Thema = :thema")
LiveData<List<Karteikarte>> getKarteikartenInBoxTopic(int Boxnummer, int thema);
```

Repository

```
public LiveData<List<Karteikarte>> getKarteikarteInBoxMixed(int boxnummer){
    return karteikarteDao.getKarteikartenInBoxMixed(boxnummer);
}

public LiveData<List<Karteikarte>> getKarteikarteInBoxTopic(Thema thema, int boxnummer){
    return karteikarteDao.getKarteikartenInBoxTopic(thema.ordinal(), boxnummer);
}
```

ViewModel

```
public LearningViewModel(Application application){
    super(application);
    repository = new KarteikarteRepository(application);
}

//This method will be called from the View at onCreate
public void initLearning(){
    allCards = repository.getKarteikarteInBoxMixed(1);
}

//This method will be called from the View
public Karteikarte nextCard() {
        // here will be a more complex algorithm
        Random random = new Random();
        List<Karteikarte> list = allCards.getValue();
        return list.get(random.nextInt(list.size()));
}
```

Comment: You're already using `Repository` inside `ViewModel` then why to use `LiveData` in `ViewModel` ? You can directly query your list in `ViewModel` from `Repository`.

Comment: The tutorials showed the Repository only passing by the LiveData it gets from the Dao. A method in the Repository calls a method in the Dao, receive LiveData from the Dao and pass that LiveData to the ViewModel. Is there any other way to manage it?!

Comment: I have added some Code to the post for better understanding how it looks like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here i have used [Transformations.switchMap()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations#switchmap) and [Transformations.map()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations#map)

For detail understanding of Transformations and MediatorLiveData, you can watch this Video from **Android Dev Summit '18** - [Fun with LiveData](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2rO4r-JOQtA)

```
private MutableLiveData<Integer> boxNumberLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
private final LiveData<List<Karteikarte>> allCardsLiveData;

//Observe this from Fragment or Activity
public final LiveData<Karteikarte> karteikarteLiveData;

LearningViewModel(){

    // when ever you change box number below function is called and list of Karteikarte will be updated
    allCardsLiveData = Transformations.switchMap(boxNumberLiveData, new Function<Integer, LiveData<List<Karteikarte>>>() {
        @Override
        public LiveData<List<Karteikarte>> apply(Integer number) {
            if(number == null)return null;
            return repository.getKarteikarteInBoxMixed(1);
        }
    });

    // when ever list of Karteikarte is changed, below function will be called and a random Karteikarte will be selected
    karteikarteLiveData = Transformations.map(allCardsLiveData, new Function<List<Karteikarte>, Karteikarte>() {
        @Override
        public Karteikarte apply(List<Karteikarte> list) {
            return getRandomKarteikarte(list);
        }
    });

}

public void initLearning(){
    //Enter box number here
    // you can modify box number anytime you want, everything will change respectively
    boxNumberLiveData.setValue(1);
}


private Karteikarte getRandomKarteikarte(@Nullable List<Karteikarte> list){
    if(list == null)return null;
    Random random = new Random();
    return list.get(random.nextInt(list.size()));
}
```

---

If you want to get the next random Karteikarte. The best way to implement this is to have a extra field in database.

```
@Entitiy:
- ID
- Question
- Answer
- Topic
- Boxnumber (Box depends on how often i was right with my Answer)
- isShown(boolean)
```

while querying the data you need to add extra condition that `isShown is false`
so when you want to load next Karteikarte, you just need to update the current Karteikarte's isShown field to true

if you want to re-use already shown Karteikarte, you can just reset isShown values to false when you want start the process

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is working good for the first card. But is there any way to trigger "getRandomKarteikarte" from my View for the second card?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Transformations](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations) to modify data in viewModel/Repository before going to Fragment or Activity

Transforamtions.map creates a New LiveData which will observe the liveData that you pass and when ever there is new data, The data will be passed though the function you provide before sending it to the Fragment or activity

```
private val liveDataFromRoomDatabase: LiveData<RecordCard> = getFromRoomDatabase()
val recordCardLiveData:LiveData<RecordCard>
    = Transformations.map(liveDataFromRoomDatabase){ recordCard ->
    // do all the changes you need here and return record card in this function
    recordCard
}
```

---

For more complex use cases you can use [MediatorLiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData)

Answer (score 0):

for live data you need use LifeCycleOwner (you need to implement in that that activity or repository or vm).Check the sample codes in google for live data

Comment: As i read a ViewModel should never be a LifeCycleOwner: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48396365/7650197

Comment: view model is not lifecycle owner .Activity or Fragment may be lifecycle owner .